# Add Icon between each Div

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple page on my site: http://jsfiddle.net/95sptas0/

Using only CSS, how do I add an icon between each `.post` div? I'd like one after each `.post` div except the last. I'm hoping to use this icon: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/arrow-down/

```css
.post {
    margin-bottom:50px;
    background:#eaeaea
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
    <h1>This is a Post</h1>
</div>

<div class="post">
    <h1>This is a Post</h1>
</div>

<div class="post">
    <h1>This is a Post</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding an icon which is not present in the DOM is something CSS cannot do. If you have the icon already there then using CSS you can hide or show element.

Comment: @Starx Thanks for the reply. So we couldn't append it to `post`, we'd actually have to have some other HTML in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After including the "FontAwesome" font, the following CSS might do it:

```
.post::after { 
    content: "\f063";
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
}
```

`\f063` is the code for the "down arrow" using the FontAwesome font.

In order for you to apply this to every element except your last, you can use the `last-of-type` selector:

```
.post:last-of-type::after { 
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I see someone has already done something similar-ish here: http://jsfiddle.net/95sptas0/4/ Using your code and this, I may just get there :) Thank you.

Comment: I did the same as an example but wasn't fast enough to answer: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/dYerRy :)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk, This is probably the way you should go, if you are set on using font awesome icons.

Comment: Thanks so much both of you. User2959229 - I'll accept your answer shortly. Thank you so much for taking the time to assist. I was getting nowhere with my tests.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk, You want the icons in between so, you need this: http://jsfiddle.net/95sptas0/7/

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much, @Starx :-)

Answer (score 3):

The font awesome icons requires to have an element with defined class. In you case this is `<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>`. Since this is a new element you cannot use CSS to handle DOM manipulation.

If you can opt for text based unicode icons and font-based icons however, it will be possible through adjacent selector.

```
.post+.post::before {
    content: "↓";
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/95sptas0/4/

Comment: Thank you again, @Starx.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk, No problem

Answer (score 1):

first download the library http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

read more here on how to use it http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/get-started/

then import it ELSE try this and play around removing the icon from heading elements

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="post">
<h1>This is a Post</h1>
</div>
<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
<div class="post">
<h1><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>This is a Post</h1>
</div>

<div class="post">
<h1><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>This is a Post</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Chrystopher - the only downside here is I don't have control over the HTML, only the CSS. Thank you for your input though, appreciate it :)